# How to import MS Outlook events?

Tags: ios, events, import, calendar, outlook

I've been told to develop an iOS 7.0 and above app which should include a way to import the user's `MS Outlook` events and show her such information within the app. This could be a quite general question, but I don't even know if it is possible to do that... Has somebody done something like that? I don't find any starting point, what would be necessary to do to import such events? Would it be mandatory to have an `Outlook.com` account synchronized in the same device, or could the events be remotely requested?

Any guidance should be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Exchange Web Services (REST API). See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for it, here is one awesome [SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS) that can help you with it. [Office365](http://dev.office.com/ios) has great set of [sample codes](http://dev.office.com/code-samples#?filters=iOS) and [training](http://dev.office.com/training#/DeepDiveIntegrateOffice365APIsinYourMobileDeviceApps) to help you with it. Hopefully this will come in handy for you. Cheers (: